# How to create a Credit Card custom payment method in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-1.9

I've searched the entire internet to look for any reference on how to create a Credit card payment method. I guess, even if you guys send me some tutorial, I'm pretty sure I've seen 'em already.

I heard that Magento is starting to deprecate the direct Credit Card payment to its future updates, just for a better security. The thing is, I'm currently using the Magento version 1.9.4.2 which the CC payment can still be implemented.

Can you guys send me a code to make a module of CC payment? Thank you in advance

BTW, this is one of the many sites out there that I found https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-payment-method-module-in-magento-part-one--cms-23464

Comment: In my opinion, you'd be hard pushed to write a custom module which is more secure than a reputable, tried and tested module. Worth noting that Magento aren't deprecating CC payments to future updates – they are dropping support for Magento 1 altogether in June – which means no security patches at all. https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/supporting-magento-1-through-june-2020

Comment: Good to know that CC payment wouldn't be deprecated. This version i'm using is the one that my supervisor told me to use because the RedHat version he let me use is 6.8 which the version of PHP it has is 5.3 and cannot be upgraded.  Meaning the Magento 2.0 and higher ones are not compatible with the softwares I'm using.

Comment: also, if you are telling me that a custom module is more secure and CC payment hasn't deprecated still. does it mean you have a CC payment module with you? Would you mind sharing it with me?

Comment: Okay, there's a whole lotta red flags here. PHP 5.3 is really (really) old and is also deprecated on 14 Aug 2014. There are 91 CVE vulnerabilities (if unpatched) https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=74&product_id=128&version_id=97802 you might want to consider seeing if your supervisor will let you upgrade to a newer version of ... everything. You're not going to be able to make or install a secure CC module on that stack. I don't have anything I can share with you, sorry. Good luck!